# when printing set an element to display inline, which was set to none

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have a table which initially hides some (history) data in a column. 
When I print the table, the hidden data is printed. This is good.
when I click the `show-history` link in the history column, the table expands and shows the hidden data.  If I then print this view, I get the hidden data. Again this is desired.
However, when I click the `hide-history` link and then print, I do not get the hidden data.  This is not good!

Here is my showHide javascript

```
function showHide(shID) {
if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
  if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
     document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
  }
  else {
     document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
     document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
  }
}
}
```

in my jsp:

```
 <a href="#" id="cID${comment.comment_id}-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('cID${comment.comment_id}');return false;">show history</a>

<TBODY id="cID${comment.comment_id}" class="more">
 .... hidden content
 <a href="#" id="cID${comment.comment_id}-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('cID${comment.comment_id}');return false;">hide history</a>
 </TBODY>
```

StyleScreen.css

```
.more {
  display: none;
}
```

StylePrint.css (this and other attempts trying to style the TBODY did not work)

```
.more {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: How and where are you loading the `StylePrint.css`?  Just a guess, but you should load it *after* your primary CSS and with the following `<link rel="stylesheet" href="StylePrint.css" type="text/css" media="print" />`

Comment: Also, if you've changed the `.more`'s inline-style to `display:none` then that style wins specificity over the style defined in `StylePrint.css`.  Try removing inline styles from `.more` with `document.getElementById(shID).style.display = '';` when hiding it.

Comment: changing my js to document.getElementById(shID).style.display = ''; (changed 'none' to '') did the trick.  I also removed .more from StylePrint.css.  How do I mark an accepted answer?

Comment: I added the above comment as an answer. glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're changing `.more`'s inline-style to `display:none` then that style wins specificity over the style defined in `StylePrint.css`.  Meaning, you can't override an inline style with a declaration in your `StylePrint.css`.

To fix:

Try removing inline styles from `.more` with `document.getElementById(shID).style.display = '';`.

This should default `.more` back to `hidden` state and allow you to override the hidden state with `StylePrint.css` when in print mode.

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript will style (hide/show) the element in the *inline way*. Having two css files with `media="screen"` and `media="print"` would have no effect.

You need to (in the "screen" css):

```
.more {
    display: none;
}

.more.show {
    display: block;
}
```

... and using JS, change the element's class (add/remove "show") instead.

Comment: this might work but I tried just changing 'none' to '' as stated in my comment above and that worked.